# How can i add a function update table and call it on link

Tags: php

Hi everyone hope you're well please i need your help if it's possible and thanks in advance.

- **My DATABASE :**
  [image: This is my database]
- **My page :**
  [image]

As you can see the problem is in the last column "Action = statut"

I want whene I click on **IN progress** the text change to **Done**

here is what i tried but it didn't work:

```
<?php 
  if ($row['statut'] == '0') { ?>
  <td><a href=" I want to call function that update table Set statut = 1 ">In progress</a></td>
  <?php }elseif($row['statut'] == '1'){?>
  <td>Done</td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Call a script that does it within the href or do an AJAX request.

Comment: The duplicate covers what you are asking for, but since you are updating data, you should not use a link. Use a form and make a POST request.

Comment: If that's what you tried, then you need to improve your HTML knowledge quite a bit - knowing what goes in the `href` in a hyperlink is fairly basic stuff that you tend to learn on day 1 of a HTML course, for example (hint: it's not plain text).